# Google PubSub no std output whilst blocking and waiting for messages

Tags: python, linux, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am listening for Google PubSub messages using the Python code at the bottom of this question. It's effectively the asynchronous pull example from Google.

I run my program and output to file:

```
python my_script.py | tee log.txt
```

If I run the program whilst messages are being received, the two `print()` statements output and everything works as expected.

However, if I run the program before messages are published there is no output. The two `print()` statements do not output, the code just blocks. I expected to see the two `print()` statements.

I tried `python my_script.py > log.txt` but it made no difference.

If I `Ctrl + C` the program the stack trace shows this:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_script.py", line 58, in <module>
    streaming_pull_future.result()
  File "python3-3.8.6-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/futures.py", line 102, in result
    err = self.exception(timeout=timeout)
  File "python3-3.8.6-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/futures.py", line 121, in exception
    if not self._completed.wait(timeout=timeout):
  File "python3-3.8.6/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 558, in wait
    signaled = self._cond.wait(timeout)
  File "python3-3.8.6/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 302, in wait
    waiter.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

My guess is the blocking call to `result()` is preventing flushing the log output to file?

Is it possible to run the program and see logging regardless of whether messages are currently being published?

If not would the logging get "flushed" eventually when messages are finally published?

Code:

```
subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project_id, subscription_id )
print(f"Subscribing to {subscription_path}..\n")
streaming_pull_future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
print(f"Listening for messages on {subscription_path}..\n")

with subscriber:
    try:
        streaming_pull_future.result()
    except TimeoutError:
        streaming_pull_future.cancel()
```

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your error. Are you using [this code sample](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#asynchronous-pull)? Could you share the rest of the code (callback function, timeout setting,...) but without any IDs.

Comment: @Ksign Yes that's the one, but obviously the Python version. Later I changed the logging from Python's print to our internal logging library and suddenly it all worked. It was as if Google uses the same Linux stream as Python uses for print() and Google was blocking it.

Comment: Good to know. Consider adding an answer to help future community members experiencing the same issue.